# Understanding the set of accumulation points of the indiscrete topology

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\tau$ be a indiscrete topology on $X$, such that $|X|\geqslant 2$.
>   $A'=\begin{cases}
> X, & \mbox{ if }|A|\geqslant 2\\
> \emptyset, & \mbox{ if }|A|=\emptyset\\
> X\setminus A & \mbox{ if }|A|=1 \end{cases},
> $

***A'***- stands for the set of accumulation points **A**

I am having a hard time understanding this example.

**Question**:

How can $X\setminus A$ be the set of accumulation points for $A$ if it does not intersect $A$? Should it not be $X$?

Comment: By adherence, you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology))? If so then you're right, as the closure of a subset $S$ of $X$ is the smallest closed set containing it, and the only closed subsets in the indiscrete topology are $\emptyset$ and $X$.

Comment: @Scientifica         Thanks for the reply! Please check my edit!

Comment: Alright! Now that's a different matter. I'll write an answer now.

Comment: "How can X∖A be the set of accumulation points for A if it does not intersect A?"  Why should A' intersect A?  There are plenty of sets where where none of the accumulations points are in $A$ (Ex. $\{\frac 1n|n\in \mathbb N\}$) Indeed if A is a set with exactly one element, that element is not an accumulation point so $A' \subset X\setminus A$ no matter what topology if $A$ has only one element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a topological space ($X$,$\tau$) and a subset $S$ of $X$, an point $x\in X$ is an accumulation point of $S$ if
$$\forall U\in\tau(x),\exists s\in S, s\neq x\land s\in U,$$
i.e, every open neighborhood of $x$ (I denote $\tau(x)$ by the set of open neighborhoods of $x$) contains a point of $S$ **different** than $x$.

Now, the indiscrete topology on $X$ is $\tau=\{\emptyset,X\}$. Let $A\subset X$ s.t $|A|=1$, i.e, $A=\{a\}$ for some $a\in X$.

According to the definition, $a$ is not an accumulation point of $A$, because there's no point in $A$ besides $a$, so you can't find points of $A$ **different** than $a$ in any open neighborhood of $a$. This shows that $A'\subset X\backslash\{a\}=X\backslash A$. ($A'$ is called [derived set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics))). Then since we're working in the indiscrete topology, you have $X\backslash A\subset A'$ as well, hence $A'=X\backslash A$.